# Access wordpress files from wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

I want to write some custom javascript code for submitting WordPress Gravity Forms. I want to write the custom js code in the WordPress files which are stored in folder prefixed with 'wp-'. However, I do only have access to WordPress admin panel "site/wp-admin".

Can you please guide me how to access the files where I can write custom js like validations and all using WordPress admin panel.

Comment: You should never edit wordpress core files, if there is an update and your wordpress is updated you will loose all your changes.  Ideally you use hooks to create your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ankit

You can use wp-file Manager plugin. You can able to access whole project files from the backend.

Thanks
Kp